# Combine categories by month using mean

Tags: r, merge

I have data (`df`) that looks like this:

| category | amount | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9 | Jan |
| B | 11 | Jan |
| C | 7 | Jan |
| D | 5 | Jan |
| E | 8 | Jan |
| A | 4 | Dec |
| B | 5 | Dec |
| C | 12 | Dec |
| D | 7 | Dec |
| E | 7 | Dec |

I want to combine `df$category` `c("C", "D", "E")` and make new category `"F"`, At the same time, I also want to average the three corresponding values in `df$amount`, as a separate amount for each `df$month` (i.e. Jan and Dec).

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifelse` we can combine the levels of `category` and `aggregate` the data.

This can be done in base R -

```
aggregate(amount~category + month,transform(df, 
         category = ifelse(category %in% c("C", "D", "E"), 'F', category)), 
          mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(category = ifelse(category %in% c("C", "D", "E"), 'F', category), month) %>%
  summarise(amount = mean(amount, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup

#  category month amount
#  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
#1 A        Dec     4   
#2 A        Jan     9   
#3 B        Dec     5   
#4 B        Jan    11   
#5 F        Dec     8.67
#6 F        Jan     6.67
```

**data**

```
df <- tructure(list(category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E"), amount = c(9L, 11L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 
7L, 7L), month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Dec", 
"Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) methods

1. Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' - `setDT`
2. Modify the 'category' with 'fifelse' by replacing some of the values to 'F'
3. Use 'category', 'month' as grouping columns
4. Get the `mean` of 'amount'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(amount = mean(amount, na.rm = TRUE)),
   .(category = fifelse(category %chin% c("C", "D", "E"), "F", category), month)]
```

---

In [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/), we collapse the values in 'category to a single one with [`fct_collapse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forcats/versions/0.5.1/topics/fct_collapse), use that as grouping column along with 'month' and get the `mean` value of 'amount' in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>%
    group_by(category = fct_collapse(category, F = c("C", "D", "E")), month) %>% 
    summarise(amount = mean(amount, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  category month amount
  <fct>    <chr>  <dbl>
1 A        Dec     4   
2 A        Jan     9   
3 B        Dec     5   
4 B        Jan    11   
5 F        Dec     8.67
6 F        Jan     6.67
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E"), amount = c(9L, 11L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 
7L, 7L), month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Dec", 
"Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```